# Is there any other proper way to have same control on two different tabs in C# form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is what I have tried and is working. But I want to whether this is proper or is there a better option or way to do the same

```
private void tabs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TabControl control = (TabControl)sender;
    if(control.SelectedIndex == 3  || control.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        button1.Parent = control.SelectedTab;
        zonalarealabel.Parent = control.SelectedTab;
        pictureBox3.Parent = control.SelectedTab;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Frontend WPF or Windows Forms? The answer varries a bit on it.

Comment: @Christopher It is a Window Form.

Comment: Windows Forms, dangit. I added the tag. | Sharing data in Windows Forms is a bit harder then it has any right to be. In WPF it can actually be trivial, once you follow the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind coupling your code to your user interface then your approach is valid. However, I think the better option is to create a user control that raises events handled by the selected tab. The user control would appear on tabs 0 and 3 at all times. The advantage of this is that you don't need to modify your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler should you want these buttons to appear on a future tab. There are many ways to approach this problem, but given the very narrow functional requirements you shared, it's a better design to relegate these buttons to a user control rather than re-parent them at runtime.